# TkInter: Squared buttons with pack manager

Tags: python, tkinter

how do I create squared buttons? I am using the pack manager, but I don't wanna change to grid or so.

```
from tkinter import*
import time

def close():
    root.destroy()

root = Tk()
root.configure(background="blue")
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, anchor=N)

close_button = Button(frame1, width=5, bg='red', fg='white', font=('Helvetica', 10), text='X', command=close)
close_button.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor=E)

frame2 = Frame(root, height=100, bg='red')
frame2.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, anchor=N)

video_button = Button(frame2, width=5, fg='white', font=('Helvetica', 10), text='X', command=close)
video_button.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor=E)

music_button = Button(frame2, width=5, bg='red', fg='white', font=('Helvetica', 10), text='X', command=close)
music_button.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor=E)

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean you want the width and height to be equal?

Buttons are funny because the width and height are set in characters, so it depends on your font.

You can override that behavior by adding an image, so you can set the side length in pixels.

```
import tkinter as tk

class SquareButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        self.img = tk.PhotoImage()
        side = kwargs.pop('side_length', None)
        tk.Button.__init__(self, master, image=self.img, compound='center', **kwargs)
        if side:
            self.config(width=side, height=side)

def close():
    root.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()

frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame1.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X, anchor=tk.N)

close_button = SquareButton(frame1, side_length=200, bg='red', fg='white', font=('Helvetica', 10), text='X', command=close)
close_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, anchor=tk.E)

frame2 = tk.Frame(root, height=100, bg='red')
frame2.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X, anchor=tk.N)

video_button = SquareButton(frame2, side_length=200, fg='white', font=('Helvetica', 10), text='X', command=close)
video_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, anchor=tk.E)

music_button = SquareButton(frame2, side_length=200, bg='red', fg='white', font=('Helvetica', 10), text='X', command=close)
music_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, anchor=tk.E)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ok now I got it. But is it possible to import tkinter without presets? (I mean instead of "import tkinter as" writing "from tkinter import *")

Comment: actually it's so ridiculous that the size settings depends on the font XD

Comment: `from tkinter import *` is called a "wildcard import". It leads to hard to read code and bugs, and therefore it's considered bad practice and it's against PEP8. So I wouldn't recommend it, but if you want you can just remove the `tk.` prefix from everything.

Comment: And it's actually very useful that the height and width are proportional to the font. Tkinter is meant to figure out most of the layout for you. If you set the size in pixels and then someone changed the font, you would loose some of the button text.